# MS Teams ThumbnailCard's button can't be clicked

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I create a thumbnailCard with bot and send it to the team message. I can click thumbnailCard's button, but the member who chat with me, can't click.

I handle this button click at OnTeamsMessagingExtensionCardButtonClickedAsync function.

Comment: Are you both using the same client (e.g. Desktop Teams versus web or mobile versions)?

Comment: @honore This is a known issue. We are checking this internally.

Comment: Could you please try adding your app to your private app store and installing it from there and then send the card using Message Extension?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT yeah,i have just use the Message Extension,I want to handle the button's click at OnTeamsMessagingExtensionCardButtonClickedAsync function,but it's no work.

Comment: Could you please try adding your app to the tenants app store and install the app from there?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT what you mean is upload app to  my organization?

Comment: @honore You could install apps that are common to your organization in your private app store. You could see private app store by clicking on Apps on the left rail[The three dots] and you will see an option "Built for YOURORG" like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnMLU.png). Only the admin of your tenant can add apps to your private app store. Please try login with an admin account and while uploading a custom app you get an option to add to your tenant. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmBU5.png. Once the app is added there you could browse to Apps for your tenant and install the app from there.